# ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

I discovered that my phpmyadmin cannot login with my root password. So I updated the password as follow:

```
# mysql 
mysql> UPDATE user set authentication_string=password('secret') where user='root';
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
```

After doing this I tried to connect with my new root password:

```
# sudo -u www-data mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I don't understand why I am still denied.

```
mysql> show grants for 'root'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+----------------+
| USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tried with:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';
```

and it worked, but I have absolutely have no idea of why any other methods do not work.

What is bizarre is that before I could connect in root with `# mysql`. Now I have to do `# mysql -uroot -p`. What did I changed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've got a similar issue, the solution:

#### 0. login to MySQL

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
use mysql;
```

#### 1. Change Password

```
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('yourpass') WHERE User='root';
```

#### 2.Change Plugin

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
```

#### 3. Finish It

```
flush privileges;
exit
```

---

#### Extra info

If you get errors like: "ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements" you can view the password rules with:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is related to socket authentication. This issue could be solved by following codes:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

Then new password for root user should be set.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'MyNewPassword';
```

Answer (score 1):

step 1. `sudo mysql -u root -p`

step 2. `USE mysql;`

step 3. `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'admin';`

Here 'admin' is your new password, yo can change it.

step 4. `exit`

Thanks. You are done.